# mysql FATAL ERROR: Could not find mysqld

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to reinstall mysql

```
make
sudo make install

cd /usr/local/mysql 

sudo ./bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql  <---- I get FATAL ERROR: Could not find mysqld
```

I think I might have another install of mysql.  How would I go about finding out if there is another install on my MAC snow leopard?

In the past 3 days I have installed mysql from dmg then unistalled then tried to install via macports then uninstall then install via tar, then uninstall then reinstall via tar, which is where I am now.

About to reformat my harddrive.

Comment: Did the semicolons get cut out of your post?  There should be some in the commands above.

Comment: no, here is where I followed how to install http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /usr/local/mysql/bin is in your PATH.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Then run the install script